# Lightning Progress Indicator setting always current step to active

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, component

I used a code from here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-progress-indicator/example for Path Type Progress Indicator example and it looks a little different - step 3 is set to active instead of to current. Is there any way to not set this step to active on start to look like in salesforce library?

[image]

```
<template>
<lightning-progress-indicator current-step="3" type="path" variant="base">
    <lightning-progress-step label="Contacted" value="1"></lightning-progress-step>
    <lightning-progress-step label="Open" value="2"></lightning-progress-step>
    <lightning-progress-step label="Unqualified" value="3"></lightning-progress-step>
    <lightning-progress-step label="Nurturing" value="4"></lightning-progress-step>
    <lightning-progress-step label="Closed" value="5"></lightning-progress-step>
</lightning-progress-indicator>
```

```
 import { LightningElement,track } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
export default class FailureOrderPage extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    
}
```

There is nothing more, no css, just code copied from library.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your code?

Comment: @NickCook already edited

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Salesforce changed this behavior in newest release 22'. On 21' works still good.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your issue, you state that step 3 is set to active instead of the current, and the code you copy pasted clearly has step 3 as the current step:

```
<lightning-progress-indicator current-step="3" type="path" variant="base">
```

so, everything seems to be working as expected.